# Is the number of cosets in $G/H$ dependent only on size of $G$ and $H$?

Tags: group-theory, elementary-set-theory

This seems like something that should be *obviously* true, yet when my friend asked me how I knew it, I couldn't come up with a proof.  And now I'm wondering if it's possible that this could somehow turn out to be false.

Suppose I have groups $A$ and $A'$ with respective subgroups $B$ and $B'$, and bijections $\phi:A\to A'$ and $\varphi:B\to B'$.

Can I say that the *sets* $A/B$ and $A'/B'$ are in $1-1$ correspondence?  I've found that what I thought would be the natural bijection $a + B\mapsto \phi(a) + B'$ need not even be well-defined.  Unfortunately this kills a two page argument that took me a whole day to write. :(  But all I need is a bijection, not an isomorphism.  Can anyone help?

(fingers crossed)

Comment: Distinct left (or right) cosets of a subgroup are disjoint, so the coset space is a partition of the group. Each coset has the same number of elements.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If $A$, $A'$ can be infinite, then this is false.  Consider $A=A'=\mathbb{Z}$, $B=\mathbb{Z}$, $B'=2\mathbb{Z}$.

If $A$ and $A'$ are finite, then there is a bijection between $A/B$ and $A'/B'$, because both sets have size $\frac{\#A}{\#B}=\frac{\#A'}{\#B'}$

Comment: That does it.  Darn.  I'll have to come up with something else.  Thanks!

Comment: @lovinglifein2012: It should be pointed out that what you are saying *does* happen in the finite case.

Comment: Yes this is what led me to jump to the incorrect conclusion.